# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'students')

Tags: javascript

so im trying to display this json data onto my app but i keep getting this error. im not sure why i cant reach the details . i tried using object keys and it will somewhat work it wont give me an error but it wont display.i dont really know why its doing what its doing since im not getting an error.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import { Input } from "@material-ui/core";

function StudentProfiles()  {

    const [info, setInfo] = useState();
    const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
    
    
    useEffect(() => {
        
         fetch("https://api.hatchways.io/assessment/students")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => setInfo(json))
    },[]);
    
    
    /*const average = (array) => array.reduce((a,b) => a + b )/ array.length;*/
    
    return (
        <div>
            <Card className="card">
                <CardContent className="scrollbar scrollbar-primary mt-5 mx-auto">
                    <Input
                    className="searchBar"
                    icon="search"
                    placeholder="Search by name"
                    />
                {info.map((name) => (
                    <ul className = "border" key={name.id}>
                    <Grid item xs={3} sm={6} md={12} style={{display: "flex", gap:"3.5rem", paddingBottom:"8px"}}>
                    <img alt ="" src={name.pic} className="picture"></img> 
                      <Grid  container style={{display: "inline"}} align="left" justify="flex-end" alignItems="flex-start">
                        <Grid  className="studentNames">
                        <span>{name.firstName + " " + name.lastName}</span>
                        </Grid>
                        <span>{name.email}</span>
                        <br/>
                        <span>{name.company}</span>
                        <br/>
                        <span>{name.skill}</span>
                        <br/>
                        <span>Average: {}%</span>
                      </Grid>
                    </Grid>
              </ul>
                ))}
               
                </CardContent>
            </Card>
        </div>
    )
}



export default StudentProfiles;
```

Comment: Where is this error?

Comment: i am getting the error : TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Comment: This error isn't the same as the error in your question's title.  Also, is it possible that ```info``` is None?  (Assuming the error is at ```info.map...```?

Comment: yes sorry i did change the code a little trying to see if something else works . so basically in the code i changed the state to " setInfo(json.students)" and then down below i changed the mapping to " {info && Object.keys(info).map(( ..." .  and what displayed is "undefined " where all the data is supposed to be. almost as if its not reading any of the data. which is weird because when i console log it its there. not so much of an error is show now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code was that when the component first rendered `info`
was empty. Therefore its value was `undefined` and did not have the property `map`.

You can easily fix this with some conditional rendering by just changing the line from `info.map()` to `info && info.map()`.

However as I was trying to reproduce the code I also found that the `typeof info` was equal to `object`. So for testing I ended up lopping though the object with `Object.entries` and so far it has worked

Granted it is different from your code but I stripped most of it away to avoid import errors. You have to change the `key` prop passed to the div in the map function, because for testing purposes I let it be the index and that it heavily discouraged.

```
import {useState, useEffect} from "react";

function StudentProfiles()  {

  const [info, setInfo] = useState();
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  
  
  useEffect(() => {
       fetch("https://api.hatchways.io/assessment/students").then((response) => {
         return response.json()
       }).then(data => {
         setInfo(data.students)
       })
  },[]);

  return (
      <div>
          {info && Object.entries(info).map(([key,value],i) => {
            return <div key={key}>{value.city}</div>
          })}
      </div>
  )
}



export default StudentProfiles;
```

Edit: The reason `info && info.map()` works is that it basically checks the first condition and if that results to `true` it does whatever is specified on the side. `&&` stands for 'and'. Traditionally you would use this in an if-else state like so:

```
if (user === "admin" && secret === "password") {
   // Do something
}
```

However in React, we can use this for conditional rendering. In the case of the question, I wanted to check if `info` contained the data. Instead of `info != undefined`, I simply used `info` as a shorthand.

Another method of conditional rendering is the ternary operator:

```
{admin? <AdminPanel/> : <UserPanel/> }
```

In this case it is basically an if-else statement. If admin is `true` show the admin panel. If not show the user panel.

You could even use it like this if retrieving the data would take a long time

```
{info? Object.entries(info).map(([key,value],i) => {
    return <div key={key}>{value.city}</div>
}) : <div>loading...</div>}
```

Comment: hey this worked !! so basically you said it wasnt mapping over any data right ? i was suspicious of that too because it kept bringing back undefined. i just didnt know how to move on forward with that though. but can you explain in more detail why changing it to info && info.map worked ?

Comment: @stackoverflowrog I edited the answer to include the explanation. Please mark as answer if it solved your problem.